# Is editing your incorrect or incomplete answer to mirror another (correct) answer allowed?

Tags: discussion

Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607812/my-webpage-wont-load-my-script-after-including-a-library/30607825#30607825) in question. Here's the timeline of events:

```
22:38:01 johnpolqkov asks question
22:38:55 ANON provides (incorrect/incomplete) answer
22:41:16 I provide the correct/complete answer
22:43:41 ANON edits his answer; his solution now directly mirrors mine
22:53:49 johnpolqkov accepts ANON's solution
00:20:38 ANON updates his answer to say exactly what I said in my answer
```

Is this fair? Is it considered plagiarism? If not, is it bad form?

I raised a custom flag, but I figured I'd bring it up on meta too.

Comment: Well at least now the question's accepted answer will receive the righteous judgement of the meta-effect.

Comment: +1 I guess you meant `ANON edits his answer; his solution now directly mirrors mine` not `ANON edits his question; his solution now directly mirrors mine`.

Comment: You forgot: `22:40:23 johnpolqkov comments on ANONs answer`. ANON gets notified and changes his answer, the code after the edit goes further than your code (notice that the `<script>` is inside the `<head>`). Stop downvoting him, his solution isn't stolen from yours.

Comment: [Here's the question's actual timeline view](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30607812/timeline?asc=True) in case anyone wants it.  I think it might be more useful.  (It's sorted from oldest events to newest events in the link I gave)

Comment: I am not sure if it is fair to include link to mentioned post in your question which can cause meta-effect, without letting accused person to defend himself. So I left link to this question under ANON post.

Comment: My answer is no way  copy cat answer. I modified the answer multiple times  because i wasn't clear of the requirement. Its a basic JS question and i m no newbie. Plus i was told to explain my answer , which i did hence the edit multiple times.

Comment: This is nonsense. It would take more than 25 seconds to comprehend the fact that your answer is better and edit your own to use the content. Shame on you.

Comment: @KenWhite what are you talking about mate

Comment: The annoying thing is that I *know* that question is a duplicate! but I can't find the right search terms (unless the earlier question(s) was/were deleted, maybe).

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried finding the duplicate too, but gave up and just ended up answering it.

Comment: Found one – and closed as dupe – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute, I think it's close enough in terms of question and answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas the problem with that one is that it doesn't give an HTML5 spec reference.

Comment: I can live with it, but by all means leave a comment to the accepted answer. Or edit the latest spec into that answer as an addenda. I'd go with a comment though, personally, with a link to the updated spec.

Comment: If my initial answer is incorrect/incomplete, I'll fix it. Sometimes this means it'll be pretty similar to existing answers that are also correct/complete. This is not the end of the world. The value of answers is in the explanation, not the code anyway.

Comment: I was in similar situation a few days ago + one more detail: after copying my answer another SO member downvoted it. It looks like such fighters feel comfortable in this site.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! This sort of thing happens to me all the time, it is particularly rife in jQuery and JavaScript tags. Honestly for the most part I just ignore it, its very annoying/frustrating but just move on to the next question.

Comment: If my answer is wrong I'll delete it. On occasion someone will post a correct answer while I'm in the middle of writing my answer, so that I won't see the new, correct answer until I finish my post - in this case, I'll delete mine if I don't think it adds value. But changing an incorrect answer to mirror someone else's correct answer smacks of being a rep whore...

Comment: @Sobrique I guess we just have different approaches. I usually delete mine, as I see no point in duplicate content, especially on simpler questions.

Answer (score 25):

Frankly, I think you've made a mountain out of a molehill, and possibly falsely denigrated someone else in the process.

Maybe the guy did just copy your big idea. But it does seem like there's pretty much just one way to address the issue; i.e. break the include and the actual script code into two different declarations. The other answerer did take a few iterations to clean up the answer so that it was useful, but I don't see how you can feel confident that he did in fact just copy over your shoulder.

How would the other answerer have fixed his answer without you coming to the conclusion you did? Especially since the only real similarity between your two answers is the one thing that pretty much *has* to be the same.

And even if he *did* copy from you, so what? I mean, sure…you have now successfully leveraged Meta mob mentality to turn your spat into a big win, reputation point-wise. But is that really the mature, professional thing to do?

IMHO, the right thing to do here would have been to just move on. No flag, no Meta question, no nothing. Stack Overflow is filled with questions that need answering; given the lack of hard evidence to support your accusation, it would have been much better to go continue helping the community, rather than spend even another moment worrying at all about this (perceived) problem.

Comment: _"Don't worry about it"_ will further set the decline of SO's quality. There's already plenty of, excusez le mot, repwhores who don't want to teach, who don't want to solve problems, but who frequent the site and sprinkle copypasta around accompanied with "Try this" or play the FGITW game without further editing their post as they harvested their upvotes anyway, as opposed to understanding, explaining and then solving the problem. Yet they get upvoted and move on to their next job with their "high-rep" SO profile, leaving the site in a worse state than it was before their participation.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I'd argue that someone who bothers fixing up their answers is much less of a burden on the community than users spitting out random answers or help vampires with thousands of low-quality questions; these are the ones getting rep from the sheer number of posts they've made.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I'm not saying to never worry about any negative behaviors. I'm saying that in this case, there's insufficient evidence and insufficient harm to spend time on the issue. Yes, FGITW exists, and maybe the questionable answer was even an example of that. But the _accusation_ was of plagiarism, with very little to support that accusation and no real obvious harm to the SO community as a whole. The OP here seems more concerned about their own rep than the overall impact to SO. That may not be "repwhore" behavior per se, but it's not exactly the purest motivation either.

Comment: This. We demand that our askers be thick skinned when we downvote/close on them; we should demand the same thick skin from answerers. The asker got the right answer. If your rep points are more important to you than that, you have a problem.

Comment: @Quantas, Peter: I'm not talking about this particular example. I'm also not talking about users who _do_ fix up their answer. I'm talking about the users who post "Try this" answers that get upvoted without properly understanding OP's problem and without explaining what the code in their answer shows. And there _are_ people who post later than you and follow your every edit. For me it's an unwritten courtesy rule that if you post basically the same answer as someone else - but later than they, you add details to make yours stand out or you delete it. Don't duplicate content.

Comment: @CodeCaster: _"I'm not talking about this particular example"_ -- well, you sure fooled me. :) It was _only_ in the context of this particular example that I suggested anything like _"don't worry about it"_. As your comment is clearly directed at the _"don't worry about it"_ scenario, and the only mention here of a scenario like that is _"this particular example"_, your comment sure _seems_ like it's about this particular example. What other _"don't worry about it"_ were you concerned about? Why did you feel that _"don't worry about it"_ was relevant here?

Comment: This: _"And even if he did copy from you, so what? [..] the right thing to do here would have been to just move on"_ - I did not take a deep dive into the correctness of the accusations of this particular example, as I was hoping OP was trying to address the broader case (and using his perceived timeline as an example), just as you kind-of seem to answer the more general case in your answer. I think I explained my stance on this case in my previous comment pretty well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think it's unfair to say `The OP here seems more concerned about their own rep than the overall impact to SO. That may not be "repwhore" behavior per se, but it's not exactly the purest motivation either.` I answer questions on SO because I enjoy helping people solve problems. What bugs me, however, is this copypasta behavior, which I see happening increasingly often as of late. Personally, if someone beats me to an answer—especially if I'm only drafting—I delete my post and leave the small difference my answer may've provided as a comment. It makes it easier for future readers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not to build a straw man, but if I cared so much about my rep, I would be whining about the deletion of the post, which cost me rep—both from the post itself and from the people who went through my profile and down voted out of spite.

Comment: @royhowie: some might say that simply mentioning the deletion of the post here is in fact "whining about it". Fact is, I have no idea what your _actual_ motivations are. I can comment only on appearances. But I can say that you are making a much bigger deal of the whole situation than it actually seems to be to me, which is really the bottom line here.

Answer (score 16):

Imho if it really was a copy-paste of another answer it should be flagged I think because you cannot simply copy content from StackOverflow without crediting the owner (they're licensed under creative commons **with attribution** [[source]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow)).

However, I personally think this question/answer is just too simple and too narrow to speak of plagiarism. Anon might not even have seen your answer and just edited his answer based on the comment of the OP.

The answer of anon now also provides additional details, so I wouldn't call it a copy.

Comment: You may be right about "Anon might not even have seen your answer" but form my experience in that case people simply leave comment denying plagiarism and explaining that they didn't even see other answers. I suspect that Anon (who is relatively new on Stack Overflow so reputation matters more here) got up-voted for his incorrect answer, but when he noticed that it was incorrect instead of deleting it he decided to correct it by using solution from other answer. That happens quite often.

Comment: @Pshemo true, I know it happens sometimes, but in this case you're almost unable to verify it. Anyways, usually when people do that, they don't add additional info, and in this case anon added information that was not available in the original answer. Good thing that it's not to me to decide whether or not it was plagiarism :p

Comment: Yes, I agree that question is no longer duplicate/plagiarism, which is good thing. I am also not saying that I am 100% sure that we ware witnesses of plagiarism here. But lets just clearly say one thing: using other people answers without attribution is wrong and should not be allowed.

Comment: If RiteshK said something like: "Edit: This is from royhowie's answer but I would like to add something else bla bla" then it would be acceptable?

Comment: @Keale good question, but I think it is yes. You see that happen quite often, if a question has quite some answers, you often also see an answer that summarizes everything from the other answers or an answer that is an addition to another answer, possibly even using content from that other answer.

Comment: @Keale for example take this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295085/how-can-i-make-an-image-carousel-with-only-css there are at least 2 answers that based themself on another answer and one even uses some similar classnames/CSS selectors, so... is that accepted? (lol, I just noticed that this question is also from OP)

Comment: @g00glen00b but they did say they were basing their answers off of mine, which fulfills the stackoverflow [CC-by-SA license requirements](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: @royhowie I know, I was just answering Keale's question, since he/she was asking if it was OK if anon added an attribution to your answer.