# Is it acceptable to edit an answer and add a solution which mirrors another within the same question?

Tags: discussion

**TL;DR**: The question is about users editing their existing answer to suggest an approach which (a) mirrors another answer to the same question (long after the other one has been posted) and (b) is completely different to their original approach. **Is it acceptable and if not, what should be done about it.**

This is not a dupe of any of the following (reasons also provided below):

- [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295905/is-editing-your-incorrect-or-incomplete-answer-to-mirror-another-correct-answe), because that talks about incorrect/incomplete original answer. In this case (hypothetical) the original answer was complete and was not incorrect.
- [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294948/plagiarism-policy-how-much-of-an-answer-can-be-copied-to-another-answer/), because we are not referring to quick answers to a common problem. The offending edit is assumed to have happened a good amount of time after the other answer was posted.
- [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution) either, because we assume there is no attribution done here.

---

**Background**

I had recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115024/weird-gradient-border-effect/31120774#31120774). There were good answers already present at the time of me answering the question but none of them covered the option that I had presented. When I checked the thread later, I found that the OP of the accepted answer had included the exact same option that I had suggested, into their answer as an edit.

There was significant time gap between the initial version of my answer and the other user's edit and also the **edit** was a completely different approach to their original answer.

I had left a comment indicating that I didn't think what they did was nice. The **user was nice enough to acknowledge that they had made a mistake** and have now removed the offending part.

However **not all users would be that nice** to acknowledge their mistake(?).

---

**Question**

So, my question is **how should we handle if such a situation arises** again in the future?

- Is it OK to leave a gentle comment like I did? (I assume it was gentle :))
- What if the user had still not removed the offending part? Are we left with no option other than using the voting buttons (or) doing nothing at all?

Let us for a minute **assume that the user had not edited out the offending part**.

- Flagging for mod attention would not have been the correct choice because there is no blatant plagiarism here ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294976/2606013))
- A rollback like suggested in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution) would have also not been applicable because it was not as if the user was quoting me within their answer.

> Please note that I have **cited the recent experience only for context setting** and better explanation of the case. I am not looking for any action or negative meta effect on the user because that case is now resolved. All that I want is the community's feedback on what I did and on how to handle such situations in the future.

Comment: So this is not specifically about people making a carbon copy of an existing answer and adding say a few words to it (which is basically plagiarism), but people repeating the same information in an answer already given - possibly because they were too lazy to read everything already answered?

Comment: @Gimby: Yes, not about obvious plagiarism. More about edge cases where we don't really know what the intention was. It could have been plain oversight like here (in which case user will most likely accept and remove) or it could have been an attempt to gain more rep by making a not so obvious copy of another answer.

Comment: _"More about edge cases where we don't really know what the intention was"_ -- IMHO, unless you can be _really sure_ about the intent, it's better to give the benefit of the doubt. Worry more about the general quality of the site, and less about individual motivations (except your own, of course...it's always worth making the effort to focus your own motivations outward to helping others, than inward to helping yourself :) ). See my answer below for my elaboration this point.

Comment: @pnuts: Yea, I agree. Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Acceptable (in isolation) and nothing should be done about it.

Without evidence of a pattern of such behaviour I would have given fellow-user Ilpo the benefit of the doubt (ie that he had not noted your answer) and have said nothing. After all the edit history is there for all to see and a little rep more or less is insignificant when all rep is of very doubtful value. So for your bullet points in order:

1 Marginal but just OK (because gentle).
2 There are options (eg bring to meta) but do nothing at all would be best.
3 Agreed.
4 Agreed.

Comment: Fair point about benefit of doubt. I agree and that's the reason why I chose not to downvote the answer even in the first place. My comment was probably the reaction of an average human being who had put in a lot of effort into their answer. On the more generic topic, finding patterns of these sort of situations is going to be very tough because one doesn't get a chance to do this every other day. Also, the linked thread was a bit unique because both answers had got sufficient attention already. (contd in next comment...)

Comment: However, consider a scenario where there are 5-6 answers and the last one (on the order of votes) has the best answer (which was not accepted for whatever reasons). Wouldn't editing one of the top answers to mirror this deny any attention to the other one? It is not all about points but shouldn't User X who had put in effort to draft a good answer get at least some reward (attention) for their work. Very rarely do visitors go deep down in a thread and read all answers.

Comment: @Harry I would keep this question purely about answer duplication and refrain from entering the gray area of attribution and entitlement / "reward", for the purposes of this meta question we're all unsung heroes.

Comment: @Gimby: I understand your point but I am just trying to play a bit of devil's advocate to see if we get a wider range of responses and/or if there is a scenario where this is not acceptable :)

Comment: @pnuts Fair enough, I agree with those comments. However, I am going to leave the thread open for some more time to see if any alternate views are provided.

Comment: @Harry: _"that's the reason why I chose not to downvote the answer even in the first place"_ -- actually, the _correct_ reason to not downvote the answer is because the answer was in fact **useful**. Voting, especially on the main site, is no place for you to let your disagreement with actions guide your own actions. The votes are there to direct other users to the most useful posts, nothing more. If you vote for other reasons (such as, you got mad at someone who you think copied your answer), **you are hurting the community**. Don't do that. Don't even consider doing that.

Comment: Yes, you're right...I actually updated the comment just before you got yours in. :) As for the voting here, as I understand it the edited answer did not have its original content removed, just some new stuff added. If it was useful before, it's still useful. That it got additional useful content that's similar to that provided elsewhere doesn't change the answer's previous usefulness, which IMHO would still hold even after the answer was added to.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I guess that comment of mine did not come out as intended. The general behavior that I have seen on the main site is to downvote and/or flag blatantly plagiarized content. Here that was not the case as I had indicated in my question itself. So I gave the user some benefit of doubt, left a comment on how I personally felt about it and did not do what I would have normally done to a plagiarized answer. This is what I meant by *chose not to downvote*. Hope it has come out right this time :)

Answer (score 4):

Not only is it acceptable, but it is by design how Stack Overflow is meant to work. Stack Overflow attempts to provide canonical answers to programming questions.

The key here is that the answer was the accepted one. The accepted answer should be as complete as possible. I have no problem with the accepted answerer coming back later to edit in more information or options to make the accepted answer even better, even if some of that information comes from other later answers on the same question, because it makes the accepted answer better for future searchers.

Let's say there is an accepted answer and later another person answers with "accepted answer works most of the time except in case X where you need to use approach Y". I believe the author of the accepted answer should edit that information into the accepted answer so that people who only read that answer are aware of case X and the alternative approach. Attribution would also be nice in this instance.

In the case you reference it is likely that the accepted answerer thought more about the problem, came to the same conclusion that you did and decided to edit that into the accepted answer to make the answer better (and actually says as much in the comments). You could have also edited your solution into the accepted answer. This is all not only acceptable but by design.

The key value we are trying to get is to have great answers to programming questions, not see who can accumulate the most magical rainbow unicorn points.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree with this on multiple counts. (a) The other answer was not accepted at the time of me posting an answer (b) It was not a community wiki and so by design I am not supposed to change its intention drastically by adding my thoughts/solution (c) Stack Overflow does allow users to add answers even after one has been accepted and that to me says that it is perfectly acceptable to add a separate answer provided it adds some extra value to the thread. (contd in next comment...)

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution?lq=1) that I had linked in my question. There is absolutely no need to duplicate the contents of another answer even with attribution.

Comment: @Harry: _"I am not supposed to change its intention drastically by adding my thoughts/solution"_ -- you are correct that you are not allowed to change the intent of a post, whether question or answer. But _extending_ an answer doesn't do that. Now, I would use that ability carefully. I agree with pnuts that it's useful to have different solutions appear in different answers. But there's no fundamental reason you _couldn't_ simply extend an existing answer; doing so doesn't harm the original content in the answer, which is the primary concern.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Sorry but I still disagree on this one and stand by my original opinion because my answer was not an extension of the original version of the other answer. It was a different solution altogether. Adding my solution into another person's answer is in my opinion equivalent to forcing my view on them.

Comment: @Harry: I'm not disputing whether your answer was appropriate in this case. I'm just commenting on the _hypothetical_ option of simply editing an existing answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Hmm, ok got you and given that context, I would agree with an edit. If we can add more details to elaborate a solution without changing its intent then it is preferable to do so.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the most important thing to **always** remember here is that our primary goal is to help other programmers. Yes, we should do so courteously, and without "cheating". But IMHO the threshold for judging someone as "cheating" should be very high; whenever possible, give the benefit of the doubt. And this is especially true if the net effect of someone's action is to make useful information more accessible (keeping in mind that I do still agree with commenter pnuts, that we don't *in general* want to go around consolidating lots of different answers into a single one…just that it hurts little and may help a lot when this happens occasionally in an "organic" way).

Indeed, the author of the other answer did IMHO behave admirably. In spite of the fact that his added content actually provided an additional option beyond the one you recommended (i.e. he removed potentially *useful* content unavailable elsewhere). He took the high road, rather than get into an extended debate with you (whether that actually would have happened, I don't know…but it's not uncommon to see, once someone has started pushing).

For example, I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt with respect to your numerous edits over the course of nearly two hours as you worked toward your complete answer. After all, that behavior does look a lot like FGITW-answering. But I'm going to assume that there was some honest, good reason to rush an answer out the door, four and a bit hours after the original question was asked, that couldn't wait another hour or so to get the proposed explanation sorted out.

And to be sure, it's nice to have such a good, detailed answer. It's always better when someone takes the time you did there, to provide not just the code change the original question needs, but to educate the questioner as to why that's the right code change, and why other approaches are inferior or don't even work. With that information, one hopes they will have an easier time comprehending the language generally (markup and formatting languages, like CSS, are IMHO particularly hard to master, because of these kinds of complex, interacting rules and behaviors).

But I note that at least one other answerer on that post provided exactly the same guidance that you and the person in question did. It's not hard to imagine that, given that's actually a good answer, multiple people might have come up with it on their own. Even a person who took a more convoluted tack on their initial answer (an answer which did apparently help the questioner in any case).

So, the next time something like this happens, I encourage you to look at the bigger picture. Rather than viewing the other person's actions through the lens of how it pertains to you personally, consider how their actions benefits or harms the community as a whole, and try to focus mainly on that. Because doing so just naturally grants the benefit of the doubt to the other person.

Yes, it's always possible they are just being a big fat jerk. But big fat jerks are everywhere, and you'll go nuts trying to deal with them all. And not everyone that seems like a big fat jerk really is one (speaking as someone who has been mistaken for one himself on a number of occasions :) ). If at the end of the day, the community is better off for those actions and those actions don't seem to be part of an on-going pattern, it may be better to just leave things well enough alone.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. I appreciate that. Indeed the other answerer behaved very admirably but that's the point behind my question as not every user would behave as admirably. Based on the responses here, I also understand that I should have just ignored the case and not left a comment.

Comment: Coming to other points, (1) *provided an additional option beyond the one you recommended* - No, it was just a shorthand version of the properties used in my answer. (2) *good reason to rush an answer out the door* - Yes, please have a look at the note in the first version of my answer. (3) *at least one other answerer on that post provided exactly the same guidance* - I am choosing not to discuss further on that because that had also happened an hour after the last major revision to my answer. You can have a look at the version history on that one to see what their original solution was too.

Comment: Elaborating a bit more on *good reason to rush an answer out the door* - The other answers (in my opinion) contained mainly workarounds on how to achieve things than a straight fix to the original problem. My answer was a solution which is why I had rushed it. I was still in the process of collecting data from credible sources and validating them before adding the explanation.