# Where do the duplication start when an answer seems similar, but not fully?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

Sometimes, answers could be very similar: use the same system/class/method/library, but they are not 100% copied.

I found an example with this question: [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java) . I take the example of using `BufferedReader` & `readLine()`, so here are the answers (ordered by score):

| Answer | Score | Date | Explanation | Try/Catch | Method | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6938341/10952503) | 267 | 2011 | No | No | Only return |  |
| [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107694/10952503) | 68 | 2013 | Not about code | Only throws | Yes | Use `System#getProperty` |
| [Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743991/10952503) | 39 | 2011 | Yes, with performance | No | No | Approach #2 |
| [Answer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949592/10952503) | 30 | 2012 | Not about code | Only throws | Yes | Say code is from Answer 1 |
| [Answer 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103484/10952503) | 22 | 2014 | Yes | Only throws | Yes | Use `char[]` |
| [Answer 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13430647/10952503) | 21 | 2012 | Yes (in comment) | Only throws | Yes |  |
| [Answer 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705517/10952503) | 1 | 2016 | Very very quick | Yes | Yes |  |
| [Answer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908771/10952503) | 1 | 2016 | No | Yes | Yes | Few days after Answer 7 |

I put, in the table, only possible differences. We can see all the answers have similarities, especially the 7 & 8. They all use the same system, with not the exact same code, or the same presentation of code (i.e., what is around the requested behavior).

Are all of those considered as duplicate? Which one should be mentioned as the main? The older? Most upvoted?

Sorry for all the questions, but it's well focused on the same beam: What should we do with very similar answers, and until when it's (or not) duplicate?

Comment: Is there reason to believe any of those answers are completely original and unlikely to have been independently reached? And when you say "duplicated/plagiarised" - you *do* understand these are completely different things, right? Because the main contention here seems to be about *similar answers* with very little, if anything, being about *plagiarism*. And plagiarism is a rather serious accusation to levy if that's not at all what you mean.

Comment: At a glance, none of those answers look even close to being plagiarism of one of the other answers.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know, that's why I'm posting this question. Yes I understand the difference. If it's consider as original answer (and not duplicate) it's rare that it's plagia. Contrary to if it's duplicate, it's also a plagia... Maybe I could add more details about both, and say that in this example, the answer 8 could be a plagia of answer 7, else I don't want to say myself if it's duplicate or plagia or nothing as it's my question

Comment: Note: "Plagia" isn't a valid abbreviation of plagiarism...

Comment: What the addressed Q&A demonstrates, is that voting doesn't work, that people overestimate their ability to write proper benchmarks, that nobody checks the memory usage of their applications (yay garbage collection) and that allowing an infinite number of answers might not be the best of ideas. But it has very little to do with duplication or plagiarism.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm too annoyed with our weather to get into a fight, but "this is how to handle plagiarism" is not a duplicate for "is this plagiarism".

Comment: @CodeCaster The answers there do discuss what "plagiarized" means, though. Sure, it's not the best dupe target, but I couldn't find a better one just yet.

Comment: Maybe I wrongly explained, but as CodeCaster said, it's not a duplicate of the mentionned post. Also, CodeCaster: why it has little to do with duplicate? All answers look the same, they are using the same code. May the code could not working properly, it's not the question.

Comment: Plagiarism is about copying existing answers. These are different enough to not be copies. There's only so many ways to write the same idiomatic code (this isn't code golf).

Comment: @Cerbrus No, it's not about what plagiarized means but until when it's not duplicate/plagiarism. You are focusing on the "plagiarism" part and ignoring the duplicate one

Comment: As for your edit, _"Can they be flagged as plagiarism when the major part is the same, except the method declariation line? Or it should be a pur copy/paste?"_ - you have to see things in context. The question you link to literally is just about reading a byte stream and converting its bytes to a string. There are not many fundamentally different ways to do so, so such a question is bound to get similar answers. It becomes more apparent at more complex questions when people copy each other's code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just take a very upvoted question to be sure it has multiple answers. Also, people could simply upvote the one they're using instead of posting the same behavior. The same problem could appear with all question, I will just not search during hours to find the same structure as it's only for the example. Also, it's not a one-line answer, that's why I choose this one

Comment: And then we're back at my previous assessment: voting doesn't work (people upvote anything that looks like code), and unconditionally allowing answers to keep flowing in (barring "protecting" a question which doesn't really do that) may not be in the best interest of quality. All of that is unrelated to your question: anyone could come up with the same code for most (reasonably) trivial questions, only for more complex code similarities begin to stand out. So what you should do in this case: downvote every latecomer posting equal answers as earlier ones and move on.

Comment: I understand for voting. Even if they comes with they own code and post it, it's a duplicate of answer as if someone come with an already posted question, it's a duplicate? So all of them are duplicate, but not plagiarism? Also, downvote will do nothing

Comment: There simply is no such thing as a duplicate answer, or at least not in things you as another user can do about them, but downvote. And indeed, in practice that accomplishes very little.

Comment: Ideally, "duplicate answers" (answers that are using the same approach as other answers *but not providing any new insights*) should just be deleted, but they may not be necessarily "plagiarised answers". One can just post an answer similar to any of those, without even reading (and thus noticing) existing answers. It happens a lot, whether they should be deleted is the community's choice, but perhaps not as "plagiarism".

Comment: A lot of late answers *are* plagiarism. The methodology: Plagiarise content from answers to the *same* Stack Overflow question, from answers to the *another* question, or from somewhere on the Internet (use a search engine and blindly copy the first result into the answer box). Alternatively, let ChatGPT generate it (but this is much easier to detect). Avoid attention and scrutiny (downvotes) in the new answer section by ***posting it as a late answer***. Optionally, strip all normal text (leaving only a code dump), so nobody will understand or care to check the technical merit of the answer.

Comment: cont' - Wait. Hope for a stray upvote (in particular, nobody will downvote a completely bogus code dump (because they don't understand it and/or it takes way too work to check and costs reputation points to do)). The more sophisticated ones first plagiarise on Medium by wholesale copying some (older) blog post outside (or [even inside](https://evan-soohoo.medium.com/dealing-with-plagiarism-1323a1ffc340)) of Medium. The goal is not plagiarism, but to do as little work as humanly possible (not producing anything of value, only increasing the entropy).

Comment: It is suspected most code dumps are a result of plagiarism, but it is very difficult to check for.

Comment: Now that the question is not about plagiarism at all, I can't see any reason for a negative reaction to it, and am personally very interested in seeing discussion. One of the biggest things preventing us from cleaning up the "long tails of crap" is answers following the pattern OP has described.

Comment: What a mess. The question is not how to do it but what the easiest way is. I'm shocked it isn't closed as being opinionated. And the top voted answer (~3400 score...) creates a giant list of ways as a response, because it is opinionated. Take your pick. Sheesh.

Comment: You should also ask here why when some users find a question already answered, down vote the existing answers and then posts their answers hoping to get up votes for them. This site is super weird. Ha ha ha

Comment: @DongLi it wouldn't be weird if all the existing answers suck.

Comment: @Gimby, there has been a big misunderstanding. I was talking about users who open an already answered question,  downvote legit answers, even the accepted one then post their own answers.

Comment: @DongLi Misunderstanding indeed. An answer being accepted in no way guarantees that it is a good answer so there is no reason to specifically call it out. What you describe is pretty much a consequence of gamification which the site endorses through its reputation points reward system, badges and unlocking of privileges. Where there are games, there are cheaters.

Comment: @Gimby, there should be a legitimate reason to justify the down voting. Why would anyone down vote a working answer?

Comment: @DongLi because it doesn't have explaination, because it doesn't works for us/not up-to-date, because it can create performance issue (or other type of issue)

Comment: @Elikill58, that is why I said the down vote should be justified by a legitimate reason which include the reasons you stated.

Comment: @DongLi There is no guarantee it actually works just  because the question author decided to click a button. I have seen people click that button as a thank you. That feature needs to be removed from the site, everyone misunderstands it and gives it too much credit.

Comment: @Gimby, good luck with that. That button is what makes people happy here. All of your reputation from that button will be undone, are you aware of that? All I said was discouraging idle down voting .

Answer (score 9):

> We can see all the answers have similarities, especially the 7 & 8. They all use the same system, with not the exact same code, or the same presentation of code (i.e., what is around the requested behavior).

Similar code isn't copied code.  Similar code isn't plagiarized code.  More than one person, with an experience in a language, could arrive at similar solutions independently.

Each person here is representing the work they did individually as their own work, and none of the code (to your own admission) is copied verbatim or close-to verbatim.

So no plagiarism here.

Comment: And what about duplicate ? Could we determine all of them as duplicate of each others ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the hang-up is here @Elikill58 - are you looking to close them all as duplicates of the same question?  That'd only make sense if the question scope and domain were very close to one another, not just because the solution is the same.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about if it were right to think they are duplicate as they have similarities

Answer (score 5):

You mention "plagiarism" and "duplication". Both have specific meanings in general, and even more so on this platform.

Plagiarism is about copying existing answers (from the same or related questions), or from external blog posts or other sources, *without attribution*. As an answerer, you should not answer a question with a copy of an answer from another question, in that case just flag the question as a duplicate. You also shouldn't copy external resources (manuals, how-to's, blogs, code sample gathering sites) without mentioning where you found them, checking their license, and linking back to them.

These answers to the question you link to, are different enough to not be copies. The question literally is just about reading a byte stream and converting its bytes to a string. Barring code golf, there are not many fundamentally different ways to do so, so such a question is bound to get similar answers.

When a question becomes more complex, people copy each other's code becomes way more apparent.

You seem to not like that people can earn reputation by merely rehashing existing answers to a popular question, and to that I agree: by adding yet another answer stating the same as existing ones, they add nothing of value to the site. They do stuff that could better be fixed by editing, and perhaps the reputation required to answer "protected" questions could increase relative to the question's "popularity".

All you can do when you see an answer that adds little value, is to downvote it. There's no other rules or actions you can apply; it is not forbidden to add another answer stating the same as existing answers in slight (or major) variations.

You cannot mark an answer as duplicate anyway.

Related:

- [When is using another poster's content plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-another-posters-content-plagiarism)
- [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers)
- [When is an answer plagiarism and should be flagged for moderator attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345217/when-is-an-answer-plagiarism-and-should-be-flagged-for-moderator-attention)

<sub>*Some phrases in this answer may be directly copied or paraphrased from the comments made by the brilliant user [CodeCaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) under [this very question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424261/where-do-the-duplication-start-when-an-answer-seems-similar-but-not-fully), who now that the question is reopened felt like those comments could be concatenated, cleaned up and summarized.*</sub>